# Oracle virtual box acces host and host vpn

Tags: macos, networking, virtualbox

I have Oracle virtualbox running on macbook OSX 10.8.2. I have a Windows 8 VM. I would like to accomplish 2 things:

- access from the vm the webserver which is running from my host
- access from the vm to webservers of my company. I can access these from my host by a VPN, can I access those hosts from my vm via the VPN which is running on my host ?

I tried bridged, host-ony adapters but that didn't do the trick so far.

Regards,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

Bridge adapter should work. How are you trying to access the VMs ? I suppose the IP will be dynamic each time so try it with host name.

Comment: I am trying the other way around,access from my vm the host where the vm is running